# C# generic factory pattern without stating the type of generic

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, factory

I am working on a C# project to parse files of different kinds. In order to do this, I have created the following kind of class structure:

```
interface FileType {}
    class FileType1 : FileType {}
    class FileType2 : FileType {}

abstract class FileProcessor<T> {}
    class Processor_FileType1 : FileProcessor<FileType1> {} 
    class Processor_FileType2 : FileProcessor<FileType2> {}
```

Now, I would like to create a factory pattern that simply takes the path to the file and **based upon the contents of the file decides which of the 2 processors to instantiate**.

Ideally (and I know this code doesn't work), I'd want my code to look something as follows:

```
class ProcessorFactory
{
    public FileProcessor Create(string pathToFile)
    {
        using (var sr = pathToFile.OpenText())
        {
            var firstLine = sr.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            if (firstLine.Contains("FIELD_A"))
                return new Processor_FileType1();

            if (firstLine.Contains("FIELD_Y"))
                return new Processor_FileType2();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue being the compiler error `Using the generic type 'FileProcessor<T>' requires 1 type arguments` 
so my program could do something like:

```
public DoWork()
{
    string pathToFile = "C:/path to my file.txt";
    var processor = ProcessorFactory.Create(pathToFile);
}
```

and the `processor` variable wold be either a `Processor_FileType1` or `Processor_FileType2`.

I know I could do it by changing the `Create` to take a type argument, but I'm hoping I won't have to since then it kills the idea of figuring it out based upon the data in the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the issue with the code in your example? Looks like it would work fine.

Comment: Sorry, @JohnWu, I updated the question - The compiler throws the error `Using the generic type 'FileProcessor<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: The easiest fix is to simply introduce a new base-class into your hierarchy, so that `FileProcessor<T> : FileProcessor`. Note that in Visual Studio you can name the file that contains `FileProcessor<T>` as `FileProcessor{T}.cs`. An interface `IFileProcessor` would be better though - abstract base classes are a little bit icky.

Comment: Another way to do it is to change `FileProcessor<T>` to `IFileProcessor<out T>`, then return a `IFileProcessor<FileType>`. A little more tricky though, as it involves covariance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. You just need one more concept in your object model, a common IFileProcessor.

```
interface FileType {}
    class FileType1 : FileType {}
    class FileType2 : FileType {}

interface IFileProcessor {}  //new
abstract class FileProcessor<T> : IFileProcessor {}
    class Processor_FileType1 : FileProcessor<FileType1> {} 
    class Processor_FileType2 : FileProcessor<FileType2> {}
```

And change your return type:

```
public IFileProcessor Create(string pathToFile)
{
    //implementation
}
```

Comment: WOW - SO FREAKING SIMPLE!!! - I'm not 100% sure why that fixes it and have to think about it more, but it did work!!!
Thank you!!!